# Correct Aria Tags?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a button with an icon that opens a mobile nav. I have on the button:

```
:aria-expanded="active" //toggled with JS
aria-controls="menu"
aria-label="Open menu"
```

The menu which includes the nav has:

```
 id="menu"
 :aria-hidden="!active"
```

There is also an `X` icon button which is placed inside the menu. It is used to close the menu; the button just has this on it:

```
aria-label="Close menu"
```

Have I correctly understood how to add aria tags? Am I missing anything? Should the `X` button also have `aria-expanded` and `aria-controls` even though it is inside the menu itself?

Comment: Rather than guess at what it looks like, can you post your HTML with the `aria` tags in place?

Comment: Why is there a colon? Is `!active` variable interpolation or the actual value? What syntax/language are you using? Agree with disinfor that we really can't help without the context of the HTML.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your menu.

### Incorrect value in aria-expanded**

The [`aria-expanded` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-expanded#values) doesn't have an "active" value, only three types:

- false;
- true;
- undefined (default type).

To inform the assistive technologies when the menu is opened the value should be **true**.

### aria label value

The value in aria-label should be informative like:

- Main navigation;
- Principal menu;
- etc.

Don't use "Open menu", the screen reader must be handling with this events by default.

The state "open", "closed" is inform with the attribute aria-expanded when applied.

### Icon X

When the icon X is inside the button hamburguer you don't need put aria-expanded and aria-controls.

Just remember to change the value of aria-label in icon Close.

```
<button aria-label="Close">X</button>
```